# How can I join 2 multi index dataframes with different levels?

Tags: python, pivot, pivot-table, multi-index, levels

df and df2 are my dataframes when I join them, it flattens the index which I don't want

`df =df.pivot_table(index=['LEVEL_3','tck'],values=['QTY'],columns=['A/B', 'YR'],aggfunc=np.sum) df2 = df.agg('sum',level =1, axis=1).add_prefix('Total ') df = df.join(df2, on=['LEVEL_3','tck']) df`

It gives the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74tyO.png)
But I want it like below, showing different levels-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZpnq.png)

What can I do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.